# How to make function make download file from path on asp.net core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I work on project use .net core 2.2 visual studio 2017 Web API

I Need to make function download file

Give function path of file will be download and download file and return Void .

I need to make function do download file on .net core 2.2 to reuse it inside action controllers .

```
public void DownloadOutPut(string path)
{
    try
    {


        if (path != "")
        {


            System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
            if (file.Exists)
            {

                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename = " + file.Name + "");
                Response.TransmitFile(path);


            }

            Response.End();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

above done on asp.net  web form I need to  do function similar to it but on .net core 2.2

so How to do it please ?

Comment: What the `path` would be? an URL of the file? Path of the file on the server or client?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a file in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45727856/how-to-download-a-file-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: https://medium.com/@tsafadi/download-a-file-with-asp-net-core-e23e8b198f74

Comment: yes solved my issue

Comment: only one question if i need to make download file downloaded on download folder and display as afile on browser this will be related to Web api or client side angular or jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are receiving a mapped path and the file is placed on your server.

```
public FileStreamResult DownloadFile(string path)
{
    var filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
    var mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
    var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);

    return new FileStreamResult(stream, mimeType) { FileDownloadName = filename };
}
```

---

For mimetypes I found this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3393525/4308286) answer helpful.