# Create a file in dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am currently in the process of updating my companies applications to dotnet 5.  One issue I have come up against in several applications is being able to create/generate a file.

The code below is how it was done in dotnet framework.

```
string output = "a very long string";

Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", output.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=test.txt");
Response.Write(output);
Response.End();
```

I have looked around and I cannot find its equivalent in dotnet core.

Comment: where to you write a file in the code provided? It looks more like an http-request to me

Comment: I think this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45728209/357561

Comment: Is this your answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897764/asp-net-core-content-disposition-attachment-inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to return a file in request (assuming you're talking about `ASP.NET Core`), you'll do:

```cs
public IActionResult ReturnAFile()
{
    ...
    // filestream in your question: stream on output
    return File(filestream, "content/type", "output.txt");
}
```

Maybe this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45728209/11473934) can give you some hints.

Comment: While that's true, it doesn't do anything like what the OP described as "create a file" in the question. The code basically shows attaching a file in an HTTP response, so I expect the OP wants to know how to do that in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Thanks for the input, never thought that I really ever would communicate with The Jon Skeet ...